# Can not bind View to ViewModel

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, view, viewmodel

I'm trying to do a simplest thing: bind a View to ViewModel, but for some reason it doesn't work.

I've got MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="ImagesToAmazon.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:ImagesToAmazon.View"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ImagesToAmazon.ViewModel" >

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MainViewModel}">
        <v:MainControl />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

</Grid>
```

MainViewModel:

```
namespace ImagesToAmazon.ViewModel{
public class MainViewModel {
}}
```

MainControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ImagesToAmazon.View.MainControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" Name="button1" Width="75" />
</StackPanel>
```

Also, I override App.OnStartup to set MainWindow context:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var window = new MainWindow();
        var viewModel = new ViewModel.MainViewModel();
        window.DataContext = viewModel;

        window.Show();
    }
}
```

All compiles, but I don't see my button from MainControl.
Any clues?

Comment: Try to read more about MVVM here:
http://galasoft.ch/mvvm/

Comment: Actually, this is usual start point to MVVM world: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx. But it looks like you should read carefully about WPF first, and than you can easily deep into MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main window, replace the Grid with

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding }" />
```

This will attempt to use the current DataContext as the content of the control, and it will use the DataTemplate u defined earlier.